# VB.NET Can not Update MSAccess DataBase Records

Tags: vb.net

```
 Private Sub btnPurchaseSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnPurchaseSave.Click
    Dim InvNo As Integer
    Dim ItmName As String
    Dim ItmType As String
    Dim ItmQuantity As Double
    Dim ItmPurPrice As Double
    Dim itmTotalCost As Double
    Dim DateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
    Dim InvTotal As Double

    InvNo = CInt(txtInvoiceNo.Text)
    InvTotal = TotalCost()

    Dim InvDate = Format(CDate(txtInvoiceDate.Text), DateFormat)

    ConnectDatabse()

    If blnPurchNew = True Then

        myConnection.Open()
        ObjCommand.CommandText = "Insert into Invoice (Invoice_No,Invoice_Date,Supplier_Name,Invoice_Total) values (@Invoice_No, @Invoice_Date,@Supplier_Name,@Invoice_Name)"
        ObjCommand.Connection = myConnection
        ObjCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Invoice_No", InvNo)
        ObjCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Invoice_Date", InvDate)
        ObjCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Supplier_Name", txtSupplierName.Text)
        ObjCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Invoice_Total", InvTotal)

        ObjCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
        ObjCommand.Dispose()

        ' Try
        For i = 0 To DGPurchase.Rows.Count - 2

            ObjCommand.CommandText = "Insert into Item_Invoice (Invoice_No,Item_Name,Item_Type,Item_Quantity,Item_Total_Cost,Item_Purchase_Price) values (@Invoice_No,@Item_Name,@item_Type, @Item_Quantity,@Item_Total_Cost,@Item_Purchase_Price)"
            ObjCommand.Connection = myConnection

            ItmName = DGPurchase.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value.ToString
            ItmType = DGPurchase.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value.ToString
            ItmQuantity = CDbl(DGPurchase.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value)
            itmTotalCost = CDbl(DGPurchase.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value)
            ItmPurPrice = CDbl(DGPurchase.Rows(i).Cells(4).Value)

            ObjCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Invoice_No", InvNo)
            ObjCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Item_Name", ItmName)
            ObjCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Item_Type", ItmType)
            ObjCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Item_Quantity", ItmQuantity)
            ObjCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Item_Total_Cost", itmTotalCost)
            ObjCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Item_Purchase_Price", ItmPurPrice)
            ObjCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
            ObjCommand.Dispose()

        Next i

        ' Catch ex As Exception

        'MsgBox(ex.Message)
        ' End Try
        MessageBox.Show("تم حفظ فاتوة المشتريات")
        lblTotalCost.Text = " الاجمالي : "
        clear()
        blnPurchNew = False

    Else
        If blnPurchModify = True Then

            myConnection.Open()
            ObjCommand.CommandText = "UPDATE Invoice SET Invoice_Date=@Invoice_Date,Supplier_Name=@Supplier_Name,Invoice_Total=@Invoice_Total WHERE Invoice_No=" & CInt(txtInvoiceNo.Text) & "  "
            ObjCommand.Connection = myConnection
            ObjCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Invoice_Date", InvDate)
            ObjCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Supplier_Name", txtSupplierName.Text)
            ObjCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Invoice_Total", InvTotal)

            ObjCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
            ObjCommand.Dispose()

            ' Try
            For i = 0 To DGPurchase.Rows.Count - 2

                ' ObjCommand.CommandText = "UPDATE Item_Invoice SET Item_Name=@Item_Name,item_Type=@item_Type, Item_Quantity=@Item_Quantity,Item_Total_Cost=@Item_Total_Cost,Item_Purchase_Price=@Item_Purchase_Price WHERE Invoice_No=@Invoice_NO"
                ObjCommand.Connection = myConnection
                ObjCommand.CommandText = "Update Item_Invoice Set Item_Name=@Item_Name Where Invoice_No=@Invoice_No"
                ItmName = DGPurchase.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value.ToString
                ItmType = DGPurchase.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value.ToString
                ItmQuantity = CDbl(DGPurchase.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value)
                itmTotalCost = CDbl(DGPurchase.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value)
                ItmPurPrice = CDbl(DGPurchase.Rows(i).Cells(4).Value)

                ObjCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Invoice_No", InvNo)
                ObjCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Item_Name", ItmName)
                ObjCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Item_Type", ItmType)
                ObjCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Item_Quantity", ItmQuantity)
                ObjCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Item_Total_Cost", itmTotalCost)
                ObjCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Item_Purchase_Price", ItmPurPrice)
                ObjCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
                ObjCommand.Dispose()

            Next i



            MessageBox.Show("تم تعديل فاتوة المشتريات")
            lblTotalCost.Text = " الاجمالي : "
            clear()
            blnPurchModify = False
        End If
    End If

    myConnection.Close()
    myConnection.Dispose()
    ObjCommand.Dispose()


End Sub
```

I am able to save Both tables and Update the first one "Invoice" but I don't know what is wrong with the second part related to Item Invoice Update.
I got No ERRORS .. I get the message of success updating with no data change in the table database.

sorry for long code, I Wanted to make it clear.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Not sure if this is the cause of your problems, but the first line inside the loops should be _objCommand.Parameters.Clear_ otherwise you continue to add parameters to the same OleDbCommand. Also the call to objCommand.Dispose should be moved at the end of the code that uses the objCommand

Comment: Thanks Steve for your quick response. I tried what you suggested with no luck. BY the Way I guess ObjCommand.Dispose at the end do the same thing as objCommand.Parameters.Clear at the beginning. moreover I use the same code and loop with Insert Statement for saving records and it is working fine. Thanks

Comment: No, Dispose destroys the objCommand. You are just lucky to not get an ObjectDisposed exception. It is fortunate for you that an OleDbCommand has no unamanaged resources to deallocate. Absolutely you should remove that line.

Comment: By the way, the Update Item_Invoice block just updates the Item_Name, the other parameters are ignored in the query

Comment: I thought that Dispose Release the Resources .. It clears the Objcommand. I use the same way for updating Invoice table as you can see in my code, and it works fine. By the way I tried exactly what you suggest with no luck moreover even Item_Name is not Updated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in the update is the definition order of the parameters.
OleDb doesn't look at the parameter's name but at the order in which the parameters are added to the collection.
In the update sql text you add first the `Invoice_No` parameter then the `Item_name` one. But in the query the first parameter placeholder is for the `Item_Name` and the last for the `Invoice_No`.

When adding the parameters you should follow the placeholder order.

```
For i = 0 To DGPurchase.Rows.Count - 2
    .....
    ObjCommand.Connection = myConnection
    ObjCommand.CommandText = "Update Item_Invoice 
          Set Item_Name=@Item_Name 
          Where Invoice_No=@Invoice_No"
    .... 

    ObjCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Item_Name", ItmName)
    ' the Invoice_No should be the last parameter added not the first
    ObjCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Invoice_No", InvNo)
    .....
    ObjCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Said that, I repeat my advice. You use always the same OleDbCommand, then do not dispose it until you have finished to use it.
Also you should clear the parameters collection between each ExecuteNonQuery. Otherwise you continue to add parameters and probably you end inserting wrong values or duplicating record in your database.

```
 Private Sub btnPurchaseSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnPurchaseSave.Click

    ....
    ConnectDatabse()

    If blnPurchNew = True Then

        myConnection.Open()
        .... 
        ObjCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

        ' Do not destroy the objCommand
        ' ObjCommand.Dispose()

        ' Try
        For i = 0 To DGPurchase.Rows.Count - 2
            ObjCommand.Parameters.Clear()
            ObjCommand.CommandText = .....
            ObjCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

            ' No destroy 
            ' ObjCommand.Dispose()

        Next i
        ....
    Else
        If blnPurchModify = True Then
            myConnection.Open()
            ObjCommand.CommandText = "UPDATE ...."
            ....
            ObjCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
            ' ObjCommand.Dispose()

            For i = 0 To DGPurchase.Rows.Count - 2
                ObjCommand.Parameters.Clear()
                ObjCommand.CommandText = "UPDATE Item_Invoice ...."
                ....
                ObjCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

            Next i
            ....
        End If
    End If

    myConnection.Close()
    myConnection.Dispose()
    ObjCommand.Dispose()
End Sub
```

Comment: It did not work this way , may I have another issue somewhere I will try to fix it. Thanks

Comment: I got my mistake. You were right @Steve , Your way works fine , the mistake was with DataBase , I have another issue now , I have one Invoice that has many Items for Example Invoice Number 2 has Orange , Apple and Banana , When view Invoice Number 2 in DataGrid and change Orange the first Item in DataGrid to Lemon using  " Update Item_Name Where Invoice_No = 2 " all items become Lemon. any Idea how to overcome and fix the problem. Thanks in Advance